# Can two exported classes in different packages interact without making their members public?

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I stumbled across this issue while working on a library and have been trying to find a solution for hours now. I'm not sure if this is even possible or not. I have a module, `com.gui`, which contains a package called `com.gui.components`, `com.gui.constraints` and `com.gui.animation`. I want to implement text-based components and set up a package called `com.gui.text`.

I have a `Font` class inside of that package (`com.gui.text`) which should be public so the user can pass it into one of the text components. However, I'm struggling with how I transfer data like the texture id over to the text component without making the variable public (or implement a public getter). I messed around with not exporting the text package and extending the Font class inside of the text component class but this seemed like a suboptimal solution and I don't really like the feel of it.

Here is the hierarchy of my project visually:

```
src/com.gui
--component -> exported
----UITextComponent

--text
----mesh
------Texture

----font -> exported
------Font // contains a Texture object which should stay invisible to the user

--XXX // other packages
```

Am I missing anything obvious here or is this impossible to do currently?

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible (answer based on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: That is true but in the same article they say: `The Java Tutorials have been written for JDK 8. Examples and practices described in this page don't take advantage of improvements introduced in later releases and might use technology no longer available.`

Comment: I can, for instance, make sure my root component deletes all of the textures created in the Font class without making the texture public by making a static method in the Texture class which deletes all of it's instances. I was wondering if something similar can be achieved

Comment: If you don't want to make the value public, you can put the two classes in the same package and declare the method protected. You can also use reflection to get the private value (but that's not recommended)

Comment: Like I said I don't really want to do that because the Font class should be in a different package (It doesn't have anything to do with components)

Comment: Why the objection to a public getter? Letting other classes get at your private data in a controlled way is exactly what a public getter is for.

Comment: Well for one, it would not be controlled as anyone has access to it then. Secondly, my Texture class doesn't get exported so the compiler complains about it

Comment: Without using reflection it is impossible to do what you want in its current form. A public getter is still a controlled way to handle your private field. Also anyone who knows java well would be able to get your private field even without a getter

Comment: that's a fair point :) I though that the way modules are packaged now might allow me to do this though

Comment: The best solution i have now is creating an inner class of my component called FontInfo and having an instance in the font class. The component can access private members of this class so that would work as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go crazy you can do the following (this is not recommended)

in your Font class have a method like this:

```
public class Font {

    private String textureId;

    ...

    public void setTextureId(Texture texture) throws Exception {
       if (texture == null) return;

       Field field = texture.getClass().getDeclaredField("textureId");
       if (field == null) return;
       field.setAccessible(true);

       textureId = String.valueof(texture.get(font));
    }
}
```

Again this is not the recommended way but it is a way to get what you want with the layout you have. Also you'd have to add some more validation checks.